# pass value of a table cell obtained by jQuery to php page

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

This is my first ever question on here and I am a bit nervous! I can obtain the value of a simple html table cell using jQuery but I cannot pass it to a php page for use as a php variable. I have been trying for 2 days using every option I have found via google - from Ajax, JSON to _POST / _GET and back again. I just can't manage it and am now in a state of total 'mind is blank'.

My test table:

```
<h3>Test Table</h3>
<table id="sourcetable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Url</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Item</th>                       
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Name 1</td>
            <td>url 1</td>
            <td>Country 1</td>
            <td>Item 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#sourcetable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        $("#fillname").val($(this).find("td").eq(1).html());
        var j=($(this).find("td").eq(1).html());
        document.getElementById("hidfo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(j); 
    });
}); 
</script>
```

I can click on a table cell and get its value and place it into an P element on the same page such as:

```
<p id="hidfo"></p>
```

or an html input field

```
<input type="text" id="fillname" value="" />
```

But everything else I have tried in relation to passing it to a php variable has failed. Ideas ?

```
AJAX

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'clicktest.php',
data: ({prod: j}),
cache: false,
success: function()
{
alert("Order Submitted");
}
});
});
</script>
```

Error Message

jQuery.Deferred exception: j is not defined @https://xxxxxx.com/portal/trans.php:127:19
l@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29373
a/https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:29677
undefined

The simple PHP i use on clicktest.php is:

```
<?php
$temp=$_POST['prod'];
echo $temp;
?>
```

on page load it gives the PHP error:

Notice: Undefined index: prod in /home/gameon/public_html/portal/clicktest.php on line 32

Comment: Okay - you are trying make `ajax`  call but finding difficult to send the data to backend running on php

Comment: Please show us your Ajax attempt. Check the console (in your browsers development tools) and share any potential errors/messages you get when trying to post it using Ajax.

Comment: What does `vardump($_POST)` give you?

Comment: var_dump($_POST)  gives array(0) { }

Answer (score 0):

You need to either define `j` outside the scope of your `.on( "click", function(` handler or invoke the AJAX call from within it, once you've obtained a value for `j`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#sourcetable tbody tr" ).on("click", function(event) {
    $("#fillname").val($(this).find("td").eq(1).html());
    var j = ($(this).find("td").eq(1).html());
    $("#hidfo").html(JSON.stringify(j)); 
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'clicktest.php',
       // You don't need the parentheses for an object; might need to wrap in JSON.stringify() call
      data: {prod: j},
      cache: false,
      success: function() {
        alert("Order Submitted");
      },
      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Failed to submit order!");
        console.error(
          "Failed to submit order! " + JSON.stringify(jqXHR) + "\n\t"
          + textStatus + "; " + errorThrown
        );
      }
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. That certainly solves the 'not defined j error'. But I still cant pass j   to the php file. I can only assume it has something to do with the data type?

Comment: I'd try using `console.log(j)` right after getting the value of `j` to see what's being passed to the PHP page (contents of `$("#hidfo")`) or setting a breakpoint on your AJAX call and inspecting `j`. Additionally, get your PHP page to log/dump the parameters it receives. Perhaps change `.html()` to `.val()` for the code that assigns to `j` (although I suspect that's invalid for anything that's not an element with a `value` property).

Comment: Using console.log the value of j is as it should be ie. the contents of the second cell in the row that is clicked. But vardump of $_POST in the php page is NULL and a PHP error of undefined  j